# Running virtual hosts in apache docker container

Tags: php, laravel, apache, docker

I have two php applications in the same apache container and I'm trying to run one of them on a port since it needs to be accessible via a root domain and not a subfolder.

I want to run the application on port 8060 which I've tried doing using apache virtual hosts but it won't load the page (http://192.168.99.100:8060/) it just says connection refused. However the normal root ip - http://192.168.99.100 works fine.
My docker file is as follows

```
version: '3.2'
  services:
    php-apache:
      build:
        context: ./apache-php
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 8060:8060

      expose:
        - '8060'
      volumes:
        - ./DocumentRoot:/var/www/html:z
```

My apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:60>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `VirtualHost` block doesn’t match your `ports:` block; I think you also need a `Listen` directive in the Apache config.  (The `expose:` block is redundant.)

Comment: How is this related to PHP, Laravel, or Docker? Please don't use unneccessary tags

Comment: @NicoHaase I understand what you're saying however the answer might not relate to any of them tags but it's a docker container running Php Laravel I didn't know what the problem was directly related to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to [@David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) I found the problem I added the listen directives to the top of my apache configuration and changed the port numbers.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  php-apache:
    build:
      context: ./apache-php
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8060:8060

    volumes:
      - ./DocumentRoot:/var/www/html:z
```

Apache config

```
Listen 80
Listen 8060

<VirtualHost *:8060>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Directory structure

```
apache-php
   ¬ sqlite3_ext
   ¬ 000-default.conf (Apache config)
   ¬ Dockerfile
   ¬ php.ini
docker-compose.yml
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2.1-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli

# Enable apache rewrite
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

#Install spatialite and create symlink for libproj.so.0
COPY sqlite3_ext /etc/sqlite3_ext
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gdal-bin
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.12 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.0

#Install gd library for images
RUN apt-get install libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev -qy \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd

#Copy php ini
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: Sir really noob to docker can you please help me step by step that how to install virtual host?

Comment: Sir I have added the folder name *vhost* docker file is in vhost folder. vhost has an another folder name *www* for my domains. where do I place the apache configuration file

Comment: @AsadKhan Not sure what you're docker setup is but I have a Dockerfile referenced by "context: ./apache-php" in my docker compose.yml as you can see above. Then in my Dockerfile I've added on line 5 (see above) a command to replace my custom apache config with the containers default apache config. I've updated my answer hopefully that'll help.

Comment: @AsadKhan I'm not very well aquainted with magento but it runs on apache still so I'd have a look at this article https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache-tips-and-tricks/rewrite-urls-with-modrewrite-and-apache/. Use the code above to copy your apache config it may not be called 000-default.conf, but if you login to the container and have a look in /etc you should be able to find it's name in the apache folder.

Comment: Thanks @Luke.T, this fixed my problem too!

Answer (score 21):

Here is a solution -- Step by Step:

**Step 1:** 
Add/Update `extra_hosts`, `hostname`, `domainname` and in `docker-compose.yml` and in my case I'm running it over PORT `80`. 
This is how my `php` service looks like in `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
php:
   build: .
   image: php:7.2-apache
   working_dir: /var/www/html
   volumes:
     - ./:/var/www/html
     - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
   extra_hosts:
     - "lara.local:127.0.0.1"
   hostname: lara.local
   domainname: local 
   ports:
     - 80:80  
   environment:
     - "DB_PORT=3306"
     - "DB_HOST=database"
```

**Step 2:** 
Update your `hosts` file with following line:

```
127.0.0.1 lara.local
```

**Step 3:** Test our hostname by running this command

```
docker exec -it <your-php-container-name> hostname
```

If you see output `lara.local` then you are good to go!

**Step 4:** Rebuild app

```
docker-compose build
```

**Step 5:** Start the services and check the app is running at `http://lara.local`

```
docker-compose up -d
```

**Note:** If you are using a different port for example `8080` then it would be `http://lara.local:8080`

> PS. If you want to change the `DocumentRoot` then ssh to your container and
>   `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and change DocumentRoot path as per your needs.

Comment: In my case the step 3 didn't work in the order you suggested. For me step 3 needed to be executed after step 5 and also had to use `docker-compose` instead of `docker`. So the command was `docker-compose exec <your-php-container-name> hostname`

Comment: This works only with a domain. And whats up on many domains?

Comment: Step 2 which `/etc/hosts` file to update? on the server itself or inside the Docker container?