# docker httpd php .htacces load but php files do not

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker-compose to load a php application which boot with a .htaccess.

If i use a proxypassmatch it works, but only for one route, as soon as the url change, the file is unfound (i read that proxypass/reverseproxy/proxypassmatch) can't be use with .htaccess ...?

If i use the traditional setting, with a virtualhost, the .htaccess is working but the php file do not load, unstead its content appear on the screen (whatever the route).

I have spent so many hours looking everywhere without any answer... Or maybe changing the image for a single container php-httpd ? but i like the idea to separate them.

If someone know how to fix it, it would be great thank you.

See the docker-compose file

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  php:
    build: './php/'
    volumes:
      - ./MediterPourGrandir/:/var/www/html/  
  apache:
    build: './apache/'
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./MediterPourGrandir/:/var/www/html/
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.40
    #restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=monsupersite
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

the apache Dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:2.4.33-alpine

RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;

# Copy apache vhost file to proxy php requests to php-fpm container

RUN sed -i '/LoadModule rewrite_module/s/^#//g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf && \
   sed -i 's#AllowOverride [Nn]one#AllowOverride All#' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

COPY demo.apache.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf
RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf" \
    >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

the apache config file

```
serverName localhost

    <VirtualHost *:80>
      
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        
        # Send apache logs to stdout and stderr
        CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
        ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
    </VirtualHost>
```

and the php Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2.7-fpm-alpine3.7

RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;

RUN apk update --no-cache \
    && apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && apk add --no-cache mysql-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally change the image (i liked not but it looks like nobody knows how to do with this one, even on Docker forum... ), i use `php:7.2.1-apache` then it works great. See the config of the docker file: [running-virtual-hosts-in-apache-docker-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939079/running-virtual-hosts-in-apache-docker-container)

I connect it to the mysql's image (like it was previously) using docker-compose.

```
  version: "3.2"
services:
  php-apache:
    build:
      context: ./apache-php
    ports:
      - 80:80  
    volumes:
      - ./MediterPourGrandir/:/var/www/html/  
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.40
    #restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=monsupersite
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
        #volumes:
        #- ./var/www/html/'monsupersite (1).sql':/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/'monsupersite (1).sql'
```